# how do I open an a single *ngIf div on *ngFor Loop

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have build a list of cards using *ngFor

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of audit">
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title>Question {{ item.questionnumber }}</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header> 
  <ion-card-content>
    {{ item.question }}
  </ion-card-content>

  <div class="contact-content">
      <ion-button class = "success" size="small" fill="outline" ><ion-icon slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>Compliant</ion-button>
      <ion-button class = "negitive" size="small" fill="outline" (click)="openSelect()"><ion-icon slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>Non-compliant</ion-button>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="show">
      <p >Show only dropdownnfo: 'one' or dropdownnfo: 'one' depending on card</p>
  </div>
```

what I want to do is when I select the Non-compliant button, I want to open the *ngIf="show" div for that card only and not all the cards on the list. this is the array that I use.  Basically only dropdownnfo: 'one' would be show when I selected the first card and nothing would be shown under the second card and vice-versa.

```
  "test": [
    { questionNumber: '1', type: 'select', question: 'What is your name. ', dropdowninfo: 'one', id: '1' },
    { questionNumber: '2',type: 'select', question: 'What is your age ?', dropdowninfo: 'Two', id: '2' }
  ]
```

This is presently what I have in my .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-side-formlist',
    templateUrl: './side-formlist.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./side-formlist.page.scss'],
  })
  export class SideFormlistPage implements OnInit {
    auditResults: any;
    auditListResults: any;
    audit: any[];

  show: boolean = false

  constructor( private storage: Storage ) { this.audit = []; }

  openSelect() {
    this.show = true;
  }

  getAuditForm() {
    this.storage.get('test').then((value) => {
      this.auditResults = JSON.parse(value);
      this.audit = this.auditResults.compliant;
      console.log('audit results',this.audit );
    });
  }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getAuditForm();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more and be clear. Is it that if you try to show an answer of one card, the answer on other cards show up as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic thing you'll need to do is to turn `show` into a dictionary of booleans, and use [the `index` value provided by `*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description) to switch on 1 of the booleans in the dictionary. And reuse the `show[index]` inside of the `*ngIf`

### TS

```js
  show: {[key: number]: boolean} = {};

  constructor( private storage: Storage ) { this.audit = []; }

  openSelect(index: number) {
    this.show[index] = true;
  }
```

### HTML

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of audit; index as i;">
   ...
      <ion-button ... (click)="openSelect(i)"> ... </ion-button>

  <div *ngIf="show[i]">
      ...
  </div>
</ion-card>
```